# writing content of listbox to a txt file and then opening it

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listbox

I am trying to save the contents of one listbox into a txt file and then open that up and printing it to a second listbox. i have done most of this, but my actual file is not a txt file. Can u show me how i make the file to be a txt file using my code? if this is not possible can u show me a code that can?

```
Private Sub LoadButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoadButton.Click
    If OpenFD.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(OpenFD.FileName)
        ListBox2.Items.Clear()
        ListBox2.Items.AddRange(lines)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SaveButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click
    If SaveFD.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Using Writer = New StreamWriter(SaveFD.FileName)
            For Each o As Object In ListBox1.Items
                Writer.WriteLine(o)
            Next
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: write strings to the file maybe.

Comment: From MSDN, `StreamWriter.WriteLine(object)`: *Writes the text representation of an object by calling the ToString method on that object, followed by a line terminator to the text string or stream.* Should be ok

Comment: What problem were you trying to solve that led to that solution? My XY question radar is going on...

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the `File.WriteAllText` method (along with a string builder).  My opinion, it's cleaner code.

```
Private Sub SaveButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click
    If SaveFD.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

        For Each o As Object In ListBox1.Items
            sb.AppendLine(o)
        Next

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("c:\mypath\output.txt", sb.ToString())
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: i am not allowed to write to a path. i have to give my program to another person so their path may be different. is there perhaps another way? i need the user to choose where to save

Comment: Then just replace `"c:\mypath\output.txt"` with `SaveFD.FileName`

Comment: I don't know why, but i have error on `sb.AppendLine(o)`. Any idea why?

Comment: @StefanĐorđević -- How can I possibly answer that if you don't tell me what the error is?

Answer (score 1):

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath & "\output.txt", sb.ToString())
```